Winforms with devexpress, binding to DataTable
I know how binding works in WPF but same in Winforms seems a tad obscure.
When binding DataTable to couple of controls, I encountered anomalies where binding on whole form seemed to become unoperational. So I tried several different ways to bind:

binding to datatable
comboBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("EditValue", dTable, "FieldName", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));

binding to dataset
comboBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("EditValue", dsData, "TableName.FieldName", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));

binding to dataview
comboBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("EditValue", dsData.Tables["Table"].DefaultView, "FieldName", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));

binding to intermediate BindingSource
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(); bs.DataSource = dsData.Tables["Table"]; comboBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("EditValue", bs, "FieldName", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));


Now, to maintain dependencies between values I attached ColumnChanged and RowChanged event handlers to DataTable. When I alter data row in these callbacks, things seem to get weirdly unstable.
When I remove the change event handlers, all methods above seem to work, also when using DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation mode.
So the questions are:

are the methods of binding above all equal? I suspect BindingSource provides some added value.

does change in underlying data, when made in ColumnChanged or RowChanged handlers somehow mess up the binding? I expected these events give me a way to use DataTable as "observable model" so I can tell when something in data changes.



I would assume they behave equal. Changing data in a XXXChanged event is weird. It will trigger a changed event again. It easy to create StackOverflows that way and presumably confuse bound Controls. But that depends on the concrete changes.

The first 3 methods are essentially the same. When you bind a DataTable, or a DataTable part of a DataSet, the binding procedure calls the  System.ComponentModel.IListSource.GetList() method (the DataTable impelements this interface), which returns the content of the DefaultView property, a DataView object. The same happens when a BindingSource is used as mediator, to fill the internal BindingList that synchronizes the source of data. The default view of a DataTable propagates INotifyPropertyChanged events. The BindingSource provides a few more notification events.

You are not supposed to change the underlying data when the ColumnChanged or RowChanged events are raised

@Jimi That explains it!
